# ¿Como obtener mas de una cierta cantidad de imagenes como respuesta de una Api?

Tags: flutter

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Me estoy basando en esta documentacion https://developers.thecatapi.com/view-account/ylX4blBYT9FaoVd6OhvR?report=bOoHBz-8t

y lo que quiero es poder obtener mas de las propiedades que aparecen aqui por defecto. en este caso 10. dice la documentacion que si se agrega el apikey delante se obtienen mas de lo que viene por defecto.

https://api.thecatapi.com/v1/images/search?limit=50&breed_ids=beng&api_key=f9891ce2-f1db-425d-bed0-0dcc1eb8be97

esta es la url en mi caso quiero 50 imagenes con sus datos pero sigo obteniendo las mismas 10. creo que es cuestion de sintaxis o no lo se.

Comment: yo veo que retorna 22, quizás lo máximo que tiene es eso

Comment: en el query parameters dice que el limite son 100 :(. toca adaptarse a lo que devuelven las url no?

Comment: así es, podrías ponerle limite mil ,pero si solo tiene 20 elementos, te retorna los 20